# How do I check if a string has a paragraph character?

Tags: vba

I need to check if a string from a word document contains a paragraph character. I want to only extract the text without the paragraph character. Is There a constant for the paragraph character? I tried checking for vbnewLine and vbCrLF, but these didn't work.

Comment: Are you referring to a paragraph mark which looks similar to a backward letter "P" (¶)? If not then please have a look at this link and confirm which mark are you referring to? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/901125

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [wikipedia article on newlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).
In total there are 3 characters indicating a new line (in some context), and sometimes they are used in combinations.
I think it does not matter which ones Word uses and which ones it doesn't; You want them all gone.

So, I'd say run through all characters and remove all LF, CR and RS instances, or replace them by spaces (whilst avoiding double spaces)

Comment: Have you tried using the character numbers? Something along the lines of this:
chr(10) //LF
chr(13) //CR